# view doesn't show list

Tags: python, html, css, django

separate index from list and create, but now
When I create a product it doesn't list and doesn't show the edit and update buttons.
the create extends view of index.

this is index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<title>Mis Productos</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head><body>
<div class="container text-center pt-5">  
<h1>Hola</h1>
<p>Inventario de productos</p>
<div class='jumbotron'>
  <center>
    <div class="text-left" style="max-width:500px">
      <form action="{% url 'index' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in register_form %}
        <div class='form-group'>
          <label for="{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
          {{ field }}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <br>
        <center><a href="{% url 'create' %}" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Registrar producto</a></center>
      </form>
    </div>
  {% block content %}  
  </center>
  <br>
  <table  class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Telefono</th>
        <th>Fecha de nacimiento</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead><tbody>
      {% for producto in productos %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ producto.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ producto.nombre }}</td>
        <td>{{ producto.precio }}</td>
        <td>{{ producto.fecha_de_vencimiento }}</td>
        <td>{{ producto.codigo_barras }}</td>
        <td><a href="update/{{producto.id}}" class="btn btn-info" id = '{{producto.id}}'>edit</a></td> 
        <td><a href="delete/{{producto.id}}" class="btn btn-danger" id = '{{producto.id}}'>delete</a</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>

</div><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-
3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384
-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jiz
o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/um
d/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-
ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
 crossorigin="anonymous">   </script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/boot
 strap.min.js" integrity="sha384-
 ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULT
 y" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

this is create.html

```
{% extends 'producto/inicio.html' %}
{% block content %}

<center>

<h1 class="display-3" style="background-color:#000000;color:#FFFF99;">
Crear Productos</h1>

<form method = 'POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}

<table class = 'w-50 table table-light' style="border-radius:10px;background-color:#FFFF99;">
{% for field in create_form %}

<tr><th>{{field.label}}</th>

<td>{{ field }}</td>

</tr>
{% endfor %}

</table>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">Submit</button>

</form>
</center>
{% endblock %}
```

When starting the django application, no error comes out, I don't know what is causing the index to not work correctly

Comment: you're using: {% extends 'producto/inicio.html' %} is this correct? It looks like you want to extend index.html

Comment: Yes, i want to extend index.html